# MSTeams Bot -how to get localTimeStamp of user when the bot is installed in a team

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created MSTeams Bot and I am using BotFramework in the service to handle all the bot events. When the user installs the bot in a team I want to get the localTimestamp of the user. In the event handler *OnInstallationUpdateAddAsync* I tried to use the context parameter of type *IInstallationUpdateActivity*, but the localTimestamp and localTimezone properties are null.
Though I am getting it in the *OnMessageActivityAsync* event handler in the context, I need to get it at the time of installation.
Please let me know if there is any way I can get this information.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We setup a sample and tested both onMessage and onInstallationUpdateActivity method to fetch localTimeStamp and localTimeZone and got the same response.

Response-

```
locale:'en-US'
   
rawTimestamp:'2024-01-23T12:41:11.4Z'
  
recipient:{id: '28:64a22b1b-1516-4b73-b094-4ca474be057d', name: 'bot-conversation'}
 
serviceUrl:'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/'
     
timestamp:Tue Jan 23 2024 18:11:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
      
type:'installationUpdate'
```

Code used-

```
  async onInstallationUpdateActivity(context) {
        if (context.activity.conversation.conversationType === 'channel') {
            await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text(`Welcome to Microsoft Teams conversationUpdate events demo bot. This bot is configured in ${context.activity.conversation.name}`));
        } else {
            await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text('Welcome to Microsoft Teams conversationUpdate events demo bot.'));
        }
    }

this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            if (context.activity.text != null) {
                const text = context.activity.text;
                console.log(context)
```

[image]

You can also refer the sample- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation/nodejs

Comment: thanks for you reply. But, the screenshot you have shared is of the node sample. "rawTimestamp" property is not present in the context we get in C#.
I have updated the screenshots in the question.

Comment: We checked using c# sample using onInstallationUpdate(), getting "localTimestamp" and "localTimeZone" as null.